# What languages use grammaticalized spoonerisms?

Tags: phonology, cross-linguistic, sandhi, grammaticalisation

Here I define a "spoonerism" as the exchange of onset sounds between initially accented words in a phrase:

- "sh(oving l)eopard" instead of "loving shepherd"
- "f(ighting a l)iar" instead of "lighting a fire"

This can be seen as long-distance metathesis like that which produced Spanish *palabra*, *milagro*, *peligro*. Or it can be infixation of modifiers ("loving" into "shepherd") or of VP heads into their nouns ("lighting" into "fire"), though I find that less likely because the article is also infixed.

*Runny Babbit* by Shel Silverstein is a "billy sook" of poetry that takes place in a fictional setting in which talking animals use spoonerisms as a normal part of their grammar.
This got me wondering if any natural languages grammaticalize this sort of long-distance metathesis of onsets.
And if so, is it commonly analyzed as infixation or metathesis?

I know of about two languages with grammatical metathesis.
One is Fur, spoken in southwestern Republic of the Sudan, which moves a verb's onset after its first vowel if the preceding pronoun ends in a consonant.
Wikipedia's article about Fur gives these examples: *lem-* "lick" > *-elm-*; *ba-* "drink" > *-ab-*.
Rotuman has similar adjacent metathesis for all but the last morpheme of a phrase.
This is metathesis but not the sort that can produce spoonerism, as it could be analyzed as an epenthetic vowel that takes the following vowel's quality due to an umlaut-like spreading phenomenon (Fur *lem-* > **-e-lem-* > *-elm*).